# Backup to Synology NAS using rsync or NFS and hardlinks

Tags: backup, nas, rsync, nfs

I want to backup data from a Windows (Vista) computer to a Synology NAS (210j). The NAS supports FTP, SMB, NFS and also allows a rsync daemon to be set up.

I want to backup different folders to the NAS, but I'd prefer to use the hardlink method to save diskspace (like [this script](http://www.heise.de/software/download/rsyncbackup.vbs/39087) does). With this method, a new folder is created for every backup, but if the file already exists on the target, only a hardlink is created.

The filesystem on the Synology device is ext3, so I probably can't use [rsyncbackup](http://www.heise.de/software/download/rsyncbackup.vbs/39087), as it is made for NTFS. Is there another way to do this backup with hardlink support?

Answer (score 1):

If the filesystem on the Synology device is ext3, it does support (in principle) hardlinks. This is the first requirement.

If you backup from a Windows computer however, hardlink creation must also be exposed (via SMB extensions) in such a way, that hardlinks can be created via the Windows API. This is the second requirement. Note that you cannot use Windows' `mklink` to test that, since `mklink` will check wether the drive is a local one and fail, even if hardlinks can actually be created via [CreateHardLinkA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createhardlinka).

Basically it depends, wether the SAMBA configuration on Linux has [Unix-Extensions](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#UNIXEXTENSIONS) enabled. If this is the case, it should work. From my experience: Most typical NAS solutions like those from Synology and QNAP actually do support this, and work out of the box.

Since you want to copy *from* the Windows computers *to* the NAS, you also don't have to set up an rsync daemon on the NAS. Backups are started and run from the clients with the scripts you mentioned.